# Commutative and anticommutative ring that respects $x^2 = 0$, where $0$ is additive identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can anyone present an example where a ring consists of infinitely many different sets/elements in a universe (ring), is both commutative and anticommutative, and respects $x \cdot x=x^2 =0$ for $\forall x$ in universe? $0$ is additive identity.

Comment: Sorry, I misread… So $x^2=0$ for all $x$ in the ring? But when $x=1$, doesn't this mean $1=0$, and so the ring is trivial? I am obviously missing something.

Comment: @Prism so the ring must be nonunital.

Comment: @blue: Makes sense, thanks. I guess I am too used to assumings ring have 1...

Comment: @blue exactly and obviously.

Comment: @ringo:  commutative means $xy = yx$ for all $x, y \in R$, and anticommutative means $xy = - yx$ for all $x, y \in R$, $R$ being the ring in question, right?

Comment: "*consists of infinitely many different sets/elements in a universe (ring),* I'm pretty sure you just want to say "having infinitely may elements." I guess this "sets/elements/universe" confusion has been caused by some introductory set theory material you've learned.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is an additive group one can equip it with the multiplication map $a\cdot b=0$ making it a ring, and this will satisfy the desired conditions with flying colors. We can make something less trivial though.

Simply generate a nonunital ring which is commutative, characteristic two, and suffiently nilpotent.

This can be done as follows: let $X$ be an infinite set (whose elements should be thought of as unknowns), and define $A$ to be the collection of all nonempty finite subsets of $X$ (which should be thought of as the collection of nontrivial monomials in our unknowns), form the space $\Bbb F_2A$ freely generated by $A$ (this is the underlying additive group of our ring) and equip it with multiplication extended from

$$U\cdot V:= \begin{cases} U\cup V & U\cap V=\emptyset \\ 0 & U\cap V\ne \emptyset. \end{cases}$$

The above expresses what it would be like to multiply monomials of commuting unknowns all satisfying the relation $x^2=0$: if the monomials share no unknown, you combine them all together, else you get the square $x^2$ of some unknown $x$ if it's in both monomials so we get $0$.

This multiplication is clearly commutative, is distributive by definition, and one easily checks that it's associative, so we do in fact have a ring on our hands.

Answer (score 1):

Take the field of two elements $F_2$.

Go into the polynomial ring $F_2[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\ldots]$ with countably many variables.

Grab the ideal $I$ generated by $\{x_i^2\mid i\in \Bbb N\}$ and the ideal $J$ generated by $\{x_i\mid i\in \Bbb N\}$.

The quotient rng $J/I$ is a commutative-and-anticommutative rng of characteristic $2$ which satisfies $X^2=0$ for all elements $X$.

The fact that it is characteristic $2$ makes commutativity and anticommutativity the same thing, and it also allows you do use the [Freshman's dream theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) to see why every element squares to $0$.